# Google Maps pixel height by latitude

Tags: google-maps, math

In Google maps, the closer one gets to the pole, the more strechted out the map gets and sp each pixel of map represents less movment (asymtotically to 0 at the north pole)

I'm looking for a formula to connect the width of a pixel in degrees to the latitute (i.e. the real world distance represented by a pixel on the map). I have some data points here for zoom level 12 (IIRC)

```
Lat Width
0   0.703107352
4.214943141 0.701522096
11.86735091 0.688949038
21.28937436 0.656590105
30.14512718 0.60989762
35.46066995 0.574739011
39.90973623 0.541457085
41.5085773  0.528679228
44.08758503 0.507194173
47.04018214 0.481321842
48.45835188 0.468430215
51.17934298 0.442887842
63.23362741 0.318394373
72.81607372 0.208953319
80.05804956 0.122131316
90  0
```

The reason for doing this is I want to input lat/lng pairs and sort out exactly what pixel they would be located with respect to 0,0

Comment: What do you mean by "height of a pixel"?

Comment: ... and "for zoom level" - for which zoom level?

Comment: height of a pixel is how much real word distance is represented by a pixel of map.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but are you sure thos points are the pixel height? They seem to be a cosine which would be the pixel width not the height.
After a little trigonometry the pixel height adjusts to the formula:

[image: Pixel height]

where R is the earth radius, phi is the latitude and h is the height of a pixel in the equator.
This formula does not adjust to your points, that's why I asked if it was the width instead.

Anyway if you want so much precision that you cannot use the approximation in the previous answer you should also consider the R variable with the latitude and even with that I don't think you'll get the exact result.

**Update**:
Then the formula would be a cosine. If you want to take the variable radius of the earth the formula would be:

[image: Pixel width]

where R is the radius of the earth and d(0) is your pixel width at the equator. You may use this formula for R assuming the eearth to be an ellipsoid:

[image: Earth radius]

with a = 6378.1 (equator) and b = 6356.8 (poles)

Comment: You're absolutely, right I meant width of a pixel at each latitude, I'll edit my question to match.

Comment: Then the formula is close to a cosine, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure what "height of a pixel" means, the plot of data (shown below) seems to fit the equation

```
y = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 where y = height, x = latitude
```

with coefficients

```
a =  7.0240278979641990E-01
b =  3.7784208874521786E-04
c = -1.2602864112736206E-04
d =  3.8304225582846095E-07
```

The general approach to find the equation is to first plot the data, then hypothesize the type of function, and then do a regression to find the coefficients.

[image: data plot]

Comment: height of a pixel is how much real word distance is represented by a pixel of map. 

I did what you did above but it only gives an approximation. I also tried some coefficients on cosine but that didn't get me all that far.